# dynamic cast of default types

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I wanted to know why the following does not work

```
 float f = 12;
 int& g = dynamic_cast<int&>(f);
```

I get the error

> cannot dynamic_cast 'f' (of type 'float') to type 'int&' (target is
>   not pointer or reference to class)
>
> ```
>  int& g = dynamic_cast<int&>(f);
> ```

I know dynamic cast deals with both pointers and references so my question is do references only work for class types and not default types ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (#5.2.7.1):

> 1 The result of the expression dynamic_cast(v) is the result of
>   converting the expression v to type T. T shall be a pointer or
>   reference to a complete **class type,** or “pointer to cv void.”